# Ubuntu.Components 1.1 missing

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

OS: Ubuntu 15.10

I installed the [ubuntu-sdk-team](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/) PPA as described on the developer page. Then launched the SDK and selected *QML App with Simple UI (qmake)*. When done, the SDK opens the *Main.qml* file.

The problem is that `import Ubuntu.Components 1.1` is missing and I have no clue how to install it.

Comment: 15.10 has not been released yet. You can report a bug. Unreleased versions are off-topic here.

Comment: Here is the bug report [#1504571](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-touch-meta/+bug/1504571).